# OBDII Based Lock/Unlock and Engine Start/Stop

Tags: obd-ii

I want to know what it takes to build a device that can Lock/Unlock door and Engine Start/Stop for vehicles using OBDII. Is it possible? The idea is to make them app connected using Bluetooth Low Energy/ or 3G that connects with he car.

If not possible via ODBII, then what is the best way to do it?

I did some search to see if there is an device that can do such a thing of the shelf which can be controlled using APIs/SDKs but all were propriety and not open for integration. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Keep in mind that the OBD II only supports the emission related data of a vehicle. But since the CAN BUS is a serial network so you might get all the data using OBD II port and not the OBD!

Lock/Unlock system is usually part of LIN system and not OBD which is a cheaper version of OBD (I think!).

CAN BUS has no encryption therefore it is possible to read all the CAN BUS traffic but the meaning of each ECU data packet is not known and manufacturers keeps them under heavy control due to the security. So if you want to have a start/stop you probably should hack the system or anyhow find the translation of each ECU data packet.

At the End if you are not a hacker with some network and vehicle knowledge, the probability is not too much for you to write an App that you expected!